# Use cylindrical coordinates to evaluate $ \int_{-2}^{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^{2}-y^{2}}} zdzdydx $

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

Use cylindrical coordinates to evaluate $ \int_{-2}^{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^{2}-y^{2}}} zdzdydx $.

**Attempt to answer:**

To use cylindrical coordinates , we at first have to identify the region of integration.

According to me the regions are hemisphere :

$ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=16, \ -2 \leq x \leq 2 , \ \ 0 \leq y \leq 2 $.

But I am not sure. Any help me finding the region and the cylindrical coordinates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \int_{-2}^{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^{2}-y^{2}}} zdzdydx $.

We know that cylindrical coordinate is defined as $$(r,\theta,z)$$

Notice that the variables are bounded by

$$-2 \leq x \leq 2$$

$$0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$$

$$0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{16-x^2-y^2} $$

The relation between r and x&y is

$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

From the given region

$$y^2+x^2=2^2$$

Know that $r \geq0$

So the region for r is $$0 \leq r \leq 2$$

Now $\theta$

We assume the direction is counter clockwise rotation.

Observe that y is always positive then, it is from $$0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$$

This is by inspection!

Also we can work it out.
Recall that

$$x=rcos\theta$$

$$x=-2$$

$$-2=2cos\theta$$

$$\theta=\pi$$

$$x=2$$

$$2=2cos\theta$$

$$\theta=0,2\pi$$

We observe that y must always be positive. $\theta$ is defined as the angle measure from the positive x-axis in a anticlockwise direction. For one compete rotation we have $0$ to $2\pi$.

First Quadrant x& y are positive

$0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Second Quadrant x is negative whereas y is still positive

$\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$

Third Quadrant x& y are negative

$\pi$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Fourth Quadrant x is positive y is negative

$\frac{3\pi}{2}$ to $2\pi$

As for z you do nothing!

$$0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{16-r^2} $$

I hope that you can carry on!